# DataTables: shift multi-select not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using `datatable 1.10`. I have already create a table, but I can't manage to do the multiple "shift select" on its rows.

According to the DataTables doc:

```
TableTools has four row selection modes of operation:
    none - Default, where no user row selection options are available
    single - A single row can be selected
    multi - Multiple rows can be selected simply by clicking on the rows
    os - Operating System like selection where you can use the shift and ctrl / cmd keys on your keyboard to add / remove rows from the selection.
```

So I create my table as follows:

```
$("#my-table-div").DataTable({
    "retrieve": true,
    "pagingType": "full_numbers",
    "pageLength": 50,
    "lengthMenu": [50, 100, 200],
    "dom": '<lfi<t>p>',
    "autoWidth": false,
    "columns": columnsTable,
    "tableTools": {
        "sRowSelect": "os"
    }
});
```

As you can see, I'm using `"sRowSelect": "os"`, but it is certainly not working as I desire. I can't get the "shift select" to work.

Any ideas on what I'm missing or doing wrong?

Comment: If you're using datatables 1.10 you shouldn't be using TableTools at all; that was the pre-1.10 extension for buttons and select. You should be using the Select extension, documented [here](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a [live example](https://jsfiddle.net/mr9Lyh59/), you need to add `dataTables.select.min.js` ressource to manage the select option. And your option : `"columns": columnsTable` is problematic.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "retrieve": true,
        "pagingType": "full_numbers",
        "pageLength": 50,
        "lengthMenu": [50, 100, 200],
        "dom": '<lfi<t>p>',
        "autoWidth": false,
        //"columns": columnsTable, <-- options problem
        "select": {
            "style": "os"
        }
    } );
} );
```

Comment: `"columns":columnsTable` is not *necessarily* a problem, as long as they have an object with the correct syntax defined prior to the initialization of the table.